# sed regexp text processing capture grouping referencing alternation confusion

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression, perl

sed's capture grouping ALTERNATION is not working as expected.

While alternation has the lowest precedence, here is the confusion:

```
echo "abcd_aefghi" | sed -r "s/(a)(b)(c)(d)|(a)(e)(f)(g)/\8/g;"

observed result --> _ghi
expected result --> error: invalid reference \8 RHS

a--bcd | # Logical alternation (Not bitwise!!)
#must be different separated logical state processing!! 
#not involvement of look behind registered reference grouping Counting!!
a--efg ;
```

also

```
sed -r "s/(a)((b)(c)(d)|(e)(f)(g))/\8/;"
observed result --> _ghi
```

more confusion if

```
sed -r "s/(a)(b)(c)(d)()|((a)(e)(f)(g))/\8/g"

observed result --> _ehi
```

also more confusion

```
sed -r "s/(a)(b)(c)(d)()||||i am Not comment, Whats going here?|||||||((a)(e)(f)(g))/\8/g"

observed result --> _ehi
expected result --> full parsing error, because "||"
```

worst is for inside grouping matching

```
echo "aBcB_aCfC" | sed -r "s/(a)((B)(c)(\1)|(C)(f)(\1))/\4/g;"
#Infield twin uppercase's must match!
observed result --> aBcB_aCfC
expected result --> c_f
```

`perl -pe` repeats the same problem!

The problem is that references counting go beyond alternation scope, rather than resetting the counting after recognizing the alternation symbol.

sed version 4.2.2 on Fedora 20.

Of course I give here the very generic-basic problem.

The real script is very complicated long text raw-parsing.

My initial goal here was to print the 4th element in each alternation mass grouping. Now I must split the match, which enlarges the code significantly.

Can someone please reduce my confusion?

Comment: Works fine for me. I'm using GNU sed 4.5. What version are you using?

Comment: show your result ??

Comment: how about the same issue: sed -r "s/(a)((b)(c)(d)|(e)(f)(g))/\8/;"

Comment: please show us how to implement with  (?|pattern) ?

Comment: Stéphane Chazelas has already added that in answer... it would help if you added some more sample input and show what is your expected output.. perhaps, something like `sed -r 's/(a)(b|e)(c|f)(d|g)/\4/g'` or `sed -r 's/(a)([be])([cf])([dg])/\4/g'` might help you as well?

Comment: yes. with Stéphane Chazelas must use perl for this simple task, and not always working AKA.

Comment: Oh, perhaps I misunderstand your question. When you say "not expected result", I interpreted it to mean "this is the expected result, but I don't see this". Do you mean "observed result" instead? If so, perhaps edit your question for clarity?

Comment: many thnx to Jeff Schaller for grammar correction!!

Answer (score 7):

`\x` is expanded to what is captured in the x<sup>th</sup> capture group, capture groups being numbered left to right based on the occurrence of the opening brace in the regexp.

```
echo "abcd_aefghi" | sed -r "s/(a)(b)(c)(d)|(a)(e)(f)(g)/\8/g;"
                               1  2  3  4   5  6  7  8
```

That regexp matches twice. Once on `abcd` (where the 8<sup>th</sup> capture group captures nothing) and once on `aefg`, where the 8<sup>th</sup> capture group captures a `g`. So `abcd` is replaced with nothing and `aefg` with `g` and `_` and `hi` are left untouched so you get `_ghi` as expected.

In:

```
sed -r "s/(a)(b)(c)(d)()|((a)(e)(f)(g))/\8/g"
          1  2  3  4  5  67  8  9  10
```

You get `_ehi` because the 8<sup>th</sup> group is now the `(e)` one.

```
sed -r "s/(a)(b)(c)(d)()||||i am Not comment, Whats going here?|||||||((a)(e)(f)(g))/\8/g"
          1  2  3  4  5                                               67  8  9  10
```

is no different. Except (though that's not visible) that because of the `||`, there will be empty matches in between `h` and `i` and an extra one at the end (a few more with `perl`).

*resetting numbers based on the alternation operator* would not make for a very usable API. If you want to expand to what is matched by the 4<sup>th</sup> capture group on either side of the alternation on your example, you can always do:

```
sed -r 's/(a)(b)(c)(d)|(a)(e)(f)(g)/\4\8/g'
          1  2  3  4   5  6  7  8
```

Which would give you the same as [`perl`'s](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#(?|pattern)):

```
perl -lpe 's/(?|(a)(b)(c)(d)|(a)(e)(f)(g))/\4/g'
                1  2  3  4   1  2  3  4
```

(where `\4` could expand to either what `(d)` or `(g)` captured).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are not happy with the given answer, as it messes your code for your real problem. Hard to help you without knowing that real problem.

To keep the fourth part of each alternation, you should probably do it differently:

```
sed -r 's/abcd|aefg/\n&/g;s/\n...//g'
```

marks each match with newline and removes the newline with the three unwanted chars in a second pass (this is GNU-`sed` only, but you could do it similar for a different `sed`).

No enlarged code with this approach. Sometimes you just need to do it differently. Of course you can also do this with groups instead of just chars.

But if this doesn't solve your real problem (and you can't figure how to adapt it), tell us your actual problem with example data.

Comment: Of course I give here the very generic-basic problem.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. And does my generic solution for your generic problem also help for your actual problem?